# Subject in a Beamer Presentation

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm making a beamer presentation for a course, I want to include the name of the course in the title page but I don't know how to do it. I tried using \subject{Name of the Course} but it doesn't do anything, is this the right command?

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid} } \title [Small Title]{Long Title} 
\author[Person1 \and Person2]{Person1 \inst{1} \and Person2 \inst{2}} 
\institute[UNI]{\inst{1} UNI \and \inst{2} UNI} \subject{Advanced Microeconometrics} 
\date{The date} 
\subject{Name of the Course} 
\begin{document} 
\justifying 
\begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please always show us a small compilable code. Without it, we have to guess around and write several lines just to help you on a little topic. Just post your title page and clarify, where you need to position the Name of the Course.

Comment: Sorry for that, here is my code:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
     }
\title [Small Title]{Long Title}

\author[Person1 \and Person2]{Person1 \inst{1} \and Person2 \inst{2}}
\institute[UNI]{\inst{1} UNI \and \inst{2} UNI}

\subject{Advanced Microeconometrics}

\date{The date}

\subject{Name of the Course}

\begin{document}
\justifying

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

Comment: Currently `\subject` just uses the argument for the PDF properties. Where do you want the name of the course to appear? (Above the title; below the title but above the author?) Please describe the desired location clearly.

Comment: Under the title, the authors and the institution but above the date please

Comment: You can "abuse" the `\author` command: `\author[Person1 \and Person2]{Person1 \inst{1} \and Person2 \inst{2}} \institute[UNI]{\inst{1} UNI \and \inst{2} UNI \\[3ex] {\large Advanced Microeconometrics}}`.

Comment: Note that you can edit your question rather than posting code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Taking from the comments and deleting one `}` you hat to much after `\usetheme{Madrid}`, adding the package `ragged2e` in order to use your command `\justifying`, and adding `\end{document}` to the end:

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title [Small Title]{Long Title} 
\author[Person1 \and Person2]{Person1 \inst{1} \and Person2 \inst{2}} 
\institute[UNI]{\inst{1} UNI \and \inst{2} UNI \\[3ex] {\large Advanced Microeconometrics}}
\date{The date} 
\subject{Name of the Course}

\begin{document} 
\justifying 
\begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]